# What is the cause of an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in my code

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

In my school assignment, I have to make recursive methods and can only use .charAt, .indexOf, .substring, .toLowerCase, .concat, and a few others that I have used in the code

This is the code

```
/*
 * Lab to perform different functions on Strings
 * all methods are static
 * only two methods should be public
 * all other methods are internal (only used in the class)
 */

package stringutil;

/**
 * @author [REDACTED]
 */

public class StringUtil {

    public static boolean inOut(String input){//the argument is in main
        int len = input.length();
        boolean test;

        input = input.toLowerCase();

        //call the cleaners
        input = StringUtil.cleanse(input, len);

        //this is le final product
        String reverse = StringUtil.flip(input);
        test = input.equals(reverse);

        return test;
    }

    private static String cleanse(String raw, int count){
        if (count < 0)
            return ("");
        //this means that there was invalid punctuation
        else{
            char ch;
            ch = raw.charAt(count);

            if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122 || ch >= 48 && ch<= 57){
                //call method again with count-1 | string is same
                return cleanse(raw, count-1);
            }
            else{ //character ain't ok yo
                if (raw.indexOf(count) == -1){
                    raw = raw.substring(raw.length()-count, count-1);
                }
                else
                    raw = raw.substring(0,count-1).concat(raw.substring(count+1));
                return cleanse(raw, count);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String flip(String input){
        String newer;
        // base case
        if (input.length() == 1){
            return input;
        }
        else{
        //take the last letter and make it the new start
            newer = input.substring(input.length()-1);
            input = input.substring(0, input.length()-1);
            return newer + flip(input);
        }
        //input = newer +
        // flip(input.substring(0, input.length()-1));
    }

/**

* @param args the command line arguments

*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println(StringUtil.flip("aashf"));
        System.out.println(StringUtil.inOut("what, t;haw"));
    }
}
```

So I get this as after running

```
fhsaa
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at stringutil.StringUtil.cleanse(StringUtil.java:36)
    at stringutil.StringUtil.inOut(StringUtil.java:21)
    at stringutil.StringUtil.main(StringUtil.java:78)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have fiddled around with the method for cleansing the characters that are not letters or numbers, but the system seems to enjoy the transfer from string to character.

My flipping method works, but my cleansing always runs into an error where it is out of range. I have tried adding many things to make sure it is in range, but that just adds to the problem.

Comment: You know that everything starts indexing at 0 right?

Comment: Yes; did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: Your first call to cleanse passes in the input and its length, and then tries to do a `charAt(length)`, which is never legal, since valid indexes are `0 ... length-1`.

Comment: What's supposed to get with `raw.indexOf(count)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of logical errors; I guess this was what you were trying to do:

```
/*
 * Lab to perform different functions on Strings
 * all methods are static
 * only two methods should be public
 * all other methods are internal (only used in the class)
 */

package stringutil;

/**
 * @author [REDACTED]
 */

public class StringUtil {

    public static boolean inOut(String input) {// the argument is in main
        int len = input.length();
        boolean test;

        input = input.toLowerCase();

        // call the cleaners
        input = StringUtil.cleanse(input, len - 1);

        // this is le final product
        String reverse = StringUtil.flip(input);
        test = input.equals(reverse);

        return test;
    }

    private static String cleanse(String raw, int count) {
        if (count < 0)
            return raw;
        // this means that there was invalid punctuation
        else {
            char ch;
            ch = raw.charAt(count);

            if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122 || ch >= 48 && ch <= 57) {
                // call method again with count-1 | string is same
                return cleanse(raw, count - 1);
            } else { // character ain't ok yo
                raw = raw.substring(0, count).concat(raw.substring(count + 1));
                return cleanse(raw, count - 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String flip(String input) {
        String newer;
        // base case
        if (input.length() == 1) {
            return input;
        } else {
            // take the last letter and make it the new start
            newer = input.substring(input.length() - 1);
            input = input.substring(0, input.length() - 1);
            return newer + flip(input);
        }
        // input = newer +
        // flip(input.substring(0, input.length()-1));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     * 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println(StringUtil.flip("aashf"));
        System.out.println(StringUtil.inOut("what, t;ahw"));
    }
}
```

---

Basically, your `// character ain't ok yo` code segment was flawed, as were your calls to `cleanse`. I haven't checked out the rest of your code, but the part of the code called in `main` seems to be working for now. Also, as a former TA, please consider adding comments to your code as you go along.

P.S.: I also changed the input string to output true for the call to `inOut`.

Answer (score 2):

Yup so `.length()` for a string returns the amount or characters within the string so you are always checking out of bounds because you need to do minus one after getting the length in order not to go out of bounds because `.charAt()` returns the letter at the specific spot

Comment: I did that and now it has an error on line 62 `newer = input.substring(input.length()-1);`

Comment: I'm debugging give me some time

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this else code block after if check

```
raw = raw.substring(0,count-1).concat(raw.substring(count+1));
```

You are trying to concat with substring for a position, which is out of bounds. count is length of the String and you are trying to make substring with count+1 position.